# A way for Revert or play back a matter.js animation?

Tags: matter.js

I would like to know if there is a way or a function to rewind an animation made with matter.js to its initial state.

The objects are present, they fall with gravity (example here : https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#mixed), and via a click for example, they would return to their initial state... I have searched in vain, but cannot find any solution.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Rewinding sort of implies stepping backwards frame by frame and reversing time, but if you just want to reset back to an original state instantaneously, you could write a function that creates all the bodies, call it once when the program starts, then destroy the bodies and call it again whenever you want to reset. The demo application you linked to pretty much does this already, with the difference that it starts and stops the whole render along with bodies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answare @ggorlen. I am looking for a way to keep the bodies and replace them where they were before the animation start, but I want to animate this transition. You talk about reversing time, or rewind but indeed, I'm more looking for a solution to go to the end of animation (what ever the actual bodies positions), and go to the first position. Did you have a suggestion? Tx again

Comment: Maybe keep track of the positions per frame as the animation runs, then when it's time to reset, pause matter.js and write your own loop that moves the bodies from position to position over time in reverse order back to the start.